# Complex geometry textbook for algebraic background

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, complex-geometry

I am looking for an introductory textbook on complex geometry. I hope there are some with algebraic point of view (I have a background in category theory, commutative algebra, a little bit of language of schemes, etc). Also I find it annoying to treat fundamental group, covering spaces and stuff like that like a reader has never seen it (for some reason every textbook on any subject tells a lot about stuff I know and skips the stuff I have problems with).

The best book I have seen on one-dimensional case (Riemann surfaces) is lectures on Riemann surfaces by Forster.

It would be great if someone knows a suitable textbook for me.

Comment: You could check out Arapura's "Algebraic Geometry over the Complex Numbers."

Answer (score 2):

I have found a great book on the subject. It’s complex variables with connections to algebraic geometry and Lie groups by J. Taylor.

Comment: I personally dislike this book, it is very watered down, and touches things on a rather superficial level.

Answer (score 0):

The best books on the subject:

1. B. V. Shabat's complex analysis in several variables (the best book on the subject).
2. Huybrecht's complex geometry.
3. Griffiths--Harris' Principles of Algebraic Geometry (A bit advanced).